# Variable "user" does not exist in my template after declaring $user in my controller

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

I try to access to my account on my website to modify an user when i'm authentificated

(old message)Orm doctrine informs me to the variable `user` does'not exists but I've declared this variable in my controlleur and I'm authenticated with my account which has the role `Admin`.

role admin has `ROLE_ADMIN` + `ROLE_USER`.

(EDIT) i delete the variable in my twig view but now, i have a new error : An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some mandatory parameters are missing ("user") to generate a URL for route "user.register".").

what parameters is missing here ? i don't understand.

I've tried to play with param converter to fix the issue, and fix the problem with a URL like /user/mon_compte/86 but it's doesn't work.
when i dd($user) in my user.register, i have 0 information, because the error is call before enter in my controller.

I really don't understand why i can't acces to my user ! i need your help !

This is my controlleur

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;


use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\UserType;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Entity;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\IsGranted;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;





#[Route('/user'), IsGranted('ROLE_USER')]
class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @var UserRepository
     */
    private $repository;
    public function __construct(UserRepository $repository, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        //em entity manager
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    
    #[Route('/mon_compte/{user}', name: 'user.register', methods: ['GET|POST'])]
    #[ParamConverter('user', options: ['mapping' => ['user' => 'id']])]
    public function userRegister(User $user, Request $request): Response
    {   
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                    $this->em->persist($user);
                    $this->em->flush();
                    $this->addFlash('success', 'Bien modifié avec succès');
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('exsana/index/html.twig');
        }

        return $this->render('userRegister.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

this is my view

```
{% if app.user %}
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a class="nav-link nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navBarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="">Profils<a/>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ path('user.register') }}" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Mon comptes </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ path('user.formations') }}" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Mes formations</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ path('user.help') }}" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Aide et assistance</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    {% endif %}
```

this is my UserAuthenticator:
my log informe me i'm auth before error
User was reloaded from a user provider.
{
"provider": "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\EntityUserProvider",
"username": "AdminEmail@Adminemail.com"
}

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;

class UsersAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $email = $request->request->get('email', '');

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $email);

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($email),
            new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', '')),
            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->request->get('_csrf_token')),
            ]
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example:
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('user.register'));
        // throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

(old message )the  first error  when i add the variable user in my twig view like

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ path('user.register', user: user.id) }}" class="nav-link text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Mon comptes </a>
```

: [image]

this is my entity user :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Serializable;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="Il y a deja un utilisateur avec cette email")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface, Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $username;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $password;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $sex;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstName;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $lastName;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $job;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $phone;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $rppsCode;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $postalCode;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $city;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $street;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $profil;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }
    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
        return array_unique($roles);
    }
    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getSex(): ?string
    {
        return $this->sex;
    }
    public function setSex(string $sex): self
    {
        $this->sex = $sex;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }
    public function setFirstName(string $firstName): self
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getLastName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }
    public function setLastName(string $lastName): self
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getJob(): ?string
    {
        return $this->job;
    }
    public function setJob(string $job): self
    {
        $this->job = $job;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getPhone(): ?string
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }
    public function setPhone(?string $phone): self
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getRppsCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->rppsCode;
    }
    public function setRppsCode(?string $rppsCode): self
    {
        $this->rppsCode = $rppsCode;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getPostalCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->postalCode;
    }
    public function setPostalCode(?string $postalCode): self
    {
        $this->postalCode = $postalCode;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getCity(): ?string
    {
        return $this->city;
    }
    public function setCity(?string $city): self
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getStreet(): ?string
    {
        return $this->street;
    }
    public function setStreet(?string $street): self
    {
        $this->street = $street;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getProfil(): ?string
    {
        return $this->profil;
    }
    public function setProfil(string $profil): self
    {
        $this->profil = $profil;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getSalt(): ?string
    {
        return null;
    }
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {

    }
    /**
     * Controls how the object is represented during PHP serialization.
     *
     * Used by PHP >= 7.4.
     *
     * @return array The properties of the object as an associative array.
     */
    public function __serialize() {
        return get_object_vars( $this );
    }
    /**
     * Controls how the object is reconstructed from a PHP serialized representation.
     *
     * Used by PHP >= 7.4.
     *
     * @param array $data The associative array representation of the object.
     * @return void
     */
    public function __unserialize( $data ) {
        foreach ( $data as $key => $value ) {
          $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }
    public function serialize() {
        return  serialize([
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password
        ]);
    }
    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password
        ) = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]); 
    }
    /**
     * Returns the identifier for this user (e.g. its username or email address).
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }
   
}
```

but now i have this error.

[image]

(EDIT)So when i add the variable {'user': user.lastname}) in my view :
i have an error who said variable don't exist

when i delete this variable, the errors is :
Some mandatory parameters are missing ("user") to generate a URL for route "user.register"

and when i try to load URL /user/mon_compte :

No route found for "GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/mon_compte

Comment: Could you add the exact error you are receiving?

Comment: It might be as simple as using the parameter name: ` #[Entity('user', option: ['id' => 'user_id'])]`  as per the [example in the docs](https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/converters.html#doctrineconverter-options).  Lowercase user instead of User.

Comment: i add the error in log and i try to write user instead User but same problem

Comment: What is line 40 in `base.html.twig`?

Comment: So you are accessing user in your base twig template.  If I had to guess the error is coming from a completely different route in which user is not being set.  By default all of your templates will be using the base template which means the twig user always has to be defined. But you also said that `Doctrine informs you that user does not exist` but I don't see an error message for that.  Maybe add a `dd($user); as the first line in your controller action and see what happens.

Comment: Also, you are not passing a `User` entity to `userRegister.html.twig` but a user id. The `path('user.register')` call will probably also fail because the argument name differs (`user` vs `user_id`). And judging by that piece of code, looks to me like any user can modify the profile of any other user. It might be a work in progress but just pointing it out.